# React-Native-Elements SearchBar Icon Not Showing

Tags: react-native

Im working on a react native app. I used react-native-elements library. The SearchBar component doesn't take the icon propery. I have imported react-native-vector-icon package as well. How to put an icon to the SearchBar?

```
<SearchBar
        placeholder="Type Comment"
        inputStyle={[styles.searchBar]}
        // noIcon={true}
        icon = {{type: 'MaterialCommunityIcons', color: '#86939e', name: 'share' }}
        clearIcon = {{type: 'MaterialCommunityIcons', color: '#86939e', name: 'share' }}
        round={true}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the [docs](https://react-native-training.github.io/react-native-elements/docs/0.19.0/icon.html#name), i think the [type](https://react-native-training.github.io/react-native-elements/docs/0.19.0/icon.html#type) should be `material-community` and not `MaterialCommunityIcons`

```
<SearchBar
        placeholder="Type Comment"
        inputStyle={[styles.searchBar]}
        // noIcon={true}
        icon = {{type: 'material-community', color: '#86939e', name: 'share' }}
        clearIcon = {{type: 'material-community', color: '#86939e', name: 'share' }}
        round={true}
```